# Select a value from a select List by value element

Tags: ruby, watir, page-object-gem

recently I came upon an issue while using page object that I could not find an answer to.

When using a select list to choose an option. I need to select by partial text or by attribute. here is an example:

```
 <select id="custcol95" name="custcol95">
      <option selected="" value="">- Select -</option>
      <option value="5">Monthly Basic Plan - $27.99</option>
      <option value="1">Monthly Business Plan - $54.99</option>
 </select>
```

I tried:

```
select_list(:planPurchase, :id => 'custcol95')
```

I can do this:

```
selectCloudPlan_element.option(:value, CLOUD_PLANS['PersonalMonthly']).select
```

but that is deprecated.

I have yet to see a select by value option or by index anywhere on the web. Does one exist?

Also if there was a search by partial text that would fix my issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The page object gem already supports selecting by partial text:

```
page.planPurchase = /Basic/
puts page.planPurchase
#=> "Monthly Basic Plan - $27.99"
```

Selecting by value is also supported by using `select_value`:

```
page.planPurchase_element.select_value('5')
puts page.planPurchase
#=> "Monthly Basic Plan - $27.99"
```

The page object gem supports selecting options by index using `[]`. Note that you have to use `.click` as there is no `.select`. The index is 0-based.

```
page.planPurchase_element[2].click
puts page.planPurchase
#=> "Monthly Business Plan - $54.99"
```

Comment: Thank you Justin. I'm surprised I tried this before and couldn't get this to work. It works perfectly now.